# Can't move DOM element to other position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

This is getting tiresome.  I'm trying to do a simple append from one element to another:

```
            var contentBlob = $('<div></div>', {
                "id"    : "content-blob",
                "css"   : {
                    "display" : "none",
                    "color" : "red"
                    }
            });

            // this guy gets a full xhtml page with head and body.  
            // I don't want to use load()
            model.getHtml(indexUrl, function(response){
                    if(response != 0){
                        contentBlob.html(response);
                    }
            });

            contentBlob.appendTo('body');
            //I've verified the that the contentBlob (#content-blob) is in the body

            // This should be super simple.  No matter what I do, Its not appending 
            // the ul.
            $('#content-blob > ul').appendTo('#contents-index-actual-index');
```

I've tripple checked the selectors, everything looks legit.  One interesting thing is that the #content-blob will append if I don't add the ul to the selector.

Comment: Is `getHTML` asynchronous? If so, then `$('#content-blob > ul').appendTo(...` is running before the `contentBlob` has been populated. I would assume it *is* async because of the callback. Move the last line of code to the callback function.

Comment: omg, thanks.  that worked!  I was spacing out last night!

Answer (score 0):

Squint was right.  The async get was happening after the appendTo.